# scala parser: know how to process a map, but don't know how to process a list of map

Tags: scala, parsing

Using the following code, I can compare a value from a key in a map with a value.
e.g"column1 > 2" will compare map("column1")>2 and result is true or false based on the map. But how to process a list of such map? I have a table in a database, so I will get a list of row, each row could be represented as a map, and then I need to process each row, and print whether the row match a condition. I knew that could be done in sql easily, but I'd like to know how this can be done in scala.

```
package test

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

object BookParse extends StandardTokenParsers {
  val lookup=Map[String,Double]("column1"->1,"column2"->2)
  lexical.delimiters ++= List(">","<",">=","!=","<>","<=","=")
  def value[double] = numericLit ^^ { s => s.toDouble }
  def columnValue[double]=ident ^^ {s=>lookup(s)}
  def condition=(columnValue|value)~(">"|"<"|"<="|">="|"<>"|"!="|"=")~(columnValue|value) ^^ {
    case left ~x ~ right=>{
      x match {
        case ">" =>if (left > right) println("true") else println("false")
        case "<" =>if (left < right) println("true") else println("false")
        case "<>"=>if (left != right) println("true") else println("false")
        case "!="=>if (left != right) println("true") else println("false")
        case ">="=>if (left >= right) println("true") else println("false")
        case "<="=>if (left <= right) println("true") else println("false")
        case "="=> if (left == right) println("true") else println("false")
      }
    }
  }

  def parse(s: String) = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
    phrase(condition)(tokens)
  }

  def test(extrString: String) = {
    parse(extrString) match {
      case Success(_,_) => println("done")
      case Failure(msg, _) => println("Failure: " + msg)
       case Error(msg, _) => println("Error: " + msg)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    test("column1 > 2")
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the data that you want to parse.

Comment: Not an answer, but the type parameters on `value` and `columnValue` aren't doing anything and could / should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slightly nicer way to do this would be to have the parsers return "expressions" that can be evaluated in the context of a map (instead of relying on side effects inside the parser).

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

object BookParse extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters ++= List(">", "<", ">=", "!=", "<>", "<=", "=")

  val value: Parser[Map[String, Double] => Double] =
    numericLit ^^ (v => _ => v.toDouble)

  val columnValue: Parser[Map[String, Double] => Double] =
    ident ^^ (name => env => env(name))

  val condition: Parser[Map[String, Double] => Boolean] =
    (columnValue | value) ~
    (">" | "<" | "<=" | ">=" | "<>" | "!=" | "=") ~
    (columnValue | value) ^^ {
      case left ~ ">"  ~ right => env => left(env) >  right(env)
      case left ~ "<"  ~ right => env => left(env) <  right(env)
      case left ~ "<>" ~ right => env => left(env) != right(env)
      case left ~ "!=" ~ right => env => left(env) != right(env)
      case left ~ ">=" ~ right => env => left(env) >= right(env)
      case left ~ "<=" ~ right => env => left(env) <= right(env)
      case left ~ "="  ~ right => env => left(env) == right(env)
    }

  def parse(s: String) = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
    phrase(condition)(tokens)
  }
}
```

Now if you've got some example data:

```
val rows: List[Map[String, Double]] = List(
  Map("column1" -> 1, "column2" -> 2),
  Map("column1" -> 3, "column2" -> 3)
)
```

You can write the following:

```
scala> val myCond = BookParse.parse("column1 > 2").get
myCond: Map[String,Double] => Boolean = <function1>

scala> rows.filter(myCond)
res0: List[Map[String,Double]] = List(Map(column1 -> 3.0))
```

(Note that there are several ways you could improve the error handling here.)